# Express JS and JWT - Token Type not shown in decoded header

Tags: json, authentication, express, jwt, express-jwt

I just added token based authentication to my express JS application - Looks like the token type doesn't show in the decoded section.

I'm testing using https://jwt.io/

Token I used to test -

```
 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiJSYW4zIiwibmFtZSI6IlJhbjMgVGVzdCJ9.YPJXc4tp8NaWcboE9obwGvm-AGa6fkN1IA6y0pT7u-w"
```

The header section just shows up

```
{
 "alg": "HS256"
}
```

I expect it to show up like this -

```
{
 "alg": "HS256",
 "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Please explain why the Token type is missing from the header?

I generate the token like this  -

```
 var token = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(user_dict), app.get('superSecret'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "type" is an optional setting on the header per the spec which is not *typically* utilized so most examples don't share how to do it. Assuming you are using this library (https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) you will be able to pass in options to the "header" via `options.header` value which should allow you to specify the field "typ":"JWT" via

```
var options = { "header": { "typ": "JWT" } };
var token = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(user_dict), app.get('superSecret'), options);
```